# How to do bulk editing in PrestaShop?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have 500 products and I want to change the names all at once. Because changing their names one-by-one can take a lot of time and effort, how can I do this in an automated way? Similarly editing quantities in bulk or some other value.

Answer (score 0):

You have many module to realize bulk editing in Prestashop:

For examples in this
http://addons.prestashop.com/en/433-fast-mass-updates

Sometimes you will not find exactly the solution you want, so the better solution is to use SQL.
You can use phpmyadmin, and create SQL:

Example 
**Bulk edit quantity**
Change all quantity for all product present in the category id(if advanced stock is not set to true)

```
UPDATE ps_product
SET quantity = 5
WHERE id_product in 
(
select id_product from ps_category_product
WHERE id_category = 3
);
```

In this example I set the quantity to 5 for all product present in the category with id = 3.

Example for changing the name :

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang
SET name = 'newname'
WHERE id_product in 
(
select id_product from ps_category_product
WHERE id_category = 3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use import & export CSV?
Export all your product in CSV format with the built-in tool, set the correct quantity using Excel or openoffice Calc and then import again.
You can do this also for other bulk modification.